# How to send a variable form my bash cgi script to my index html page?

Tags: javascript, html, bash, frontend, cgi

I have a homepage ./index.html, and on this page I would like to display a variable that was created in my ./cgi-bin/print_ip.sh file.

What is the cleanest way of accomplishing this?

Comment: The cleaner way is to have `index.html` generated dynamically. The easier way is to have a small `iframe`. If it should remain static and you want it well integrated into the page, use a bit of JS to request the value and insert it into the page.

Comment: How would the javascript retrieve this variable from the cgi bash script? 
`ip=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)`

Comment: The cgi bash script would have to output it

Comment: The bash script does output it as part of the html it renders, is there a method for in javascript for retrieving from this generated html file?

Comment: People often [use jquery to fetch a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640626/getting-data-from-cgi-into-javascript-ajax/16641218)

Answer (score 0):

if you can use shtml, take a look at here https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/shtml.htm

shtml is like html where you can dynamicly include some stuff from the  webserver:

```
<!--#exec cmd="cgi-bin/mycounter.cgi" -->
<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/mycounter.cgi" -->
<insert file="cgi-bin/mycounter.cgi">
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
```